# How to determine VB app compile/created date

Tags: vb.net, vb6, updates, decompiling

My company uses a software that, in the footer of it's about section lists the year 2001-2002.  Is this sufficient grounds to believe that the last major overhaul or update that this program received would have been in 2001-02?

If not, is there a way through decompiling the software, it's written in VB6?

Comment: The dates in about just mean that was the last time the dev updated that text, though it is likely to be close.  Decompiling wont yield the answer - why do you care?

Comment: Because my company is locked in a contract with the company whose software we are using...they say they update at regular intervals but the UI seems seriously dated and the About menu is generally a good indication of when it was last updated...to summarize we are looking for a way out of the contract and believe this to be key.  There must be some way of finding out, through digging through the code or otherwise.

Comment: Find the oldest machine in the org running the software.  Find the disk file in Explorer, then Right Click, select Properties - examine the "Created" Date.  It will be the date that file was created on that disk - which could be install date, restore date or last update installed date.  They cant have updated or at least distributed a new ver to that computer since that date.  I doubt it will say 200X unless the computer is running XP and is itself 14 years old

Comment: `There must be some way of finding out` you dont have records of when new software was received or installed?  Even correspondence indicating whats new in this version, or that there IS a new version or how to install?

Comment: The software belongs to a multinational company, we only have it running on 1 server and 2 workstations.  The only files that we have access to are the install files and the files that are subsequently unpacked.  Incidentally one of the laptops in the office is running XP, although this is a personal preference of its user and nothing to do with its age.  I appreciate your responses by the way, also please note it's tenterhooks, not tinterhooks.  Maybe there in fact isn't a way to digitally extract the last update timestamp, it just would have been a great angle to have.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I forgot the linker sticks a timestamp into the PE Header.  Here is a short VB.NET applet to read the PE Header and convert the timestamp:

```
Private Function GetPEDate(filename As String) As DateTime

    Dim dtUINT As UInt32
    Using fs As Stream = New FileStream(filename, 
                        FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read),
        rdr As New BinaryReader(fs)

        ' move to PE location (60; 70 for 64 bit but
        ' there is no such thing as a 64bit VB6 app)
        fs.Position = &H3C
        Dim peHDR As UInt32 = rdr.ReadUInt32()       ' offset of start location
        fs.Position = peHDR

        Dim tmpUINT = rdr.ReadUInt32()            ' PE sig
        Dim tmpShrt = rdr.ReadUInt16              ' machine
        tmpShrt = rdr.ReadUInt16                  ' sections

        dtUINT = rdr.ReadUInt32()                 ' linker timestamp

    End Using
    ' SEE NOTE
    Dim dtCompiled As New DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)

    dtCompiled = dtCompiled.AddSeconds(dtUINT)
    dtCompiled = dtCompiled.AddHours( _ 
            TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.GetUtcOffset(dtCompiled).Hours)

    Return dtCompiled
End Function
```

To use it:

```
Dim dt = GetPEDate(FullFilePath)
Console.WriteLine("App was compiled approx: {0}", dt.ToString)
```

Output:

> App was compiled approx: 4/6/2004 11:54:07 AM

I tested this with some actual old VB6 apps as well as some x86 VB.NET apps and the `DateTime` returned is spot on compared to that of CreatedDate and/or Modified Date reported by Explorer.

Initially the time was off by 3 hours.  The [MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms809762.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) clearly state:

> This field holds the number of seconds since December 31st, 1969, at 4:00 P.M.

But it was off by exactly 3 hrs and my TZ is not 3 away from East Coast US, Seattle or GMT.  A quick Google yielded [this article by Jeff Atwood](http://blog.codinghorror.com/determining-build-date-the-hard-way/) (which includes another PE reader). Changing the base date to 1/1/1970 00:00:00 and adding the UTC adjustment returns times matching Explorer.

Apparently MSDN is wrong or out of date as to the base date. `1/1/1970` also seems more likely since corresponds to POSIX/Unix timestamps.

Answer (score 1):

From WinNT.h note second DWord, TIMEDATESTAMP

```
typedef struct _IMAGE_FILE_HEADER {
    WORD    Machine;
    WORD    NumberOfSections;
    DWORD   TimeDateStamp;
    DWORD   PointerToSymbolTable;
    DWORD   NumberOfSymbols;
    WORD    SizeOfOptionalHeader;
    WORD    Characteristics;
} IMAGE_FILE_HEADER, *PIMAGE_FILE_HEADER;
```

If you look here you'll find above explained and a program to do it for you as well.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms809762.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396